# A better algorithm to find the minimum polynomial of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory, minimal-polynomials

For a square matrix $M$, I was taught the following algorithm to find the minimum polynomial:
First, choose a random vector $v$ and hope it isn't an eigenvector of $M$, and compute 
$$Mv$$
Create the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}Mv\end{bmatrix}$$
And row reduce. If it is linearly independent, repeat the process to create
$$\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}Mv\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}M^2v\end{bmatrix}$$
And row reduce again. Repeat until the composed matrix is linearly dependent. Now, just read off of the final column vector to compute the minimum polynomial in the form
$$M^nv = a_{n-1}M^{n-1}v +a_{n-2}M^{n-2}v+.....+a_1Mv+a_0 $$
Which all makes sense. I get the advantages here, for example if you ever see a relationship like $Mv=2M^2v$ in the composed matrix, then you are done since the minimum polynomial is just $2M^2v-Mv=0 \rightarrow 2x^2-x=0$. However, there are clear disadvantages like choosing an eigenvector for the random vector, which would lead to this recursive algorithm never ending. My question is, is there a better, more reliable algorithm? I understand that this is a good algorithm for computing the minimum polynomial by hand, but it clearly has some faults. I will be tested on this on paper, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How large will the matrix be? One method would be to compute the characteristic polynomial and try to reduce it.

Comment: @Math1000 Likely $3x3$ or $4x4$. Last midterm we were given a $4x4$ matrix but it had a lot of zeroes, so computing the characteristic polynomial would be doable. What is the method to reduce the characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ and $r$ be the degree of its minimal polynomial. Starting from a random vector $v$, the method that you expose works with probability $1$ (it's not obvious to prove; we can do that, using the Frobenius form).

Using sophisticated methods, the calculation of the minimal polynomial $m_A$ has complexity $O(n^3)$. Thus, the above method is interesting only when $r/n$ is small. Indeed, the calculation of $(M^kv)_{k\leq r+1}$ has complexity $O(rn^2)$ and the calculation of the reduced row echelon form of these vectors too.

Conclusion. The considered method is fast  when $r=o(n)$ but, above all, it is very easy to program.

Now, you want to use this method -by hand- for $n\leq 4$. I don't see the interest. Indeed, if $\chi_A$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has simple roots, then $m_A=\chi_A$; otherwise, $\chi_A$ has  a multiple root that is rational and that you can explicitly calculate.

Comment: Given only $X_A$, how do you calculate $m_A$? The only time you can be *certain* they are equal is if $X_A$ has roots all of degree $1$. The interest is to inevitably write the JNF after finding $X_A$ and $m_A$

Comment: I  only wrote that when the multiple roots are rational, then the problem is not interesting (because very easy). On the other hand, when $n\geq 5$, we never calculate the JNF. Indeed, with probability $1$, one cannot calculate explicitly the eigenvalues. Even for $n=4$ the explicit calculation of the JNF, is very computational. My conclusion: the method using pseudo-cyclic vector is spectacular when $n=10$ for example, with the help of a PC. Now, you do as you want...

Comment: Thank you, I see now.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is you know that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial and that the minimal polynomial and characteristic polynomial have the same distinct roots. Therefore you can reduce the degrees of repeated roots in the characteristic polynomial to see if the minimal polynomial is of smaller degree than the characteristic polynomial. 
    Another way you can compute the minimal polynomial is by computing the Jordan canonical form of the matrix. The multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a root in the minimal polynomial will then be the dimension of the largest Jordan block associated with $\lambda$.

Comment: But in order to compute the JNF (by hand at least) you need both the charpol and the minpol, so that’s not too much help unless it’s given before hand. And how do you know what the multiplicity will be in the minpol after computing the charpol? In other words, how do you know when to stop reducing the roots of the eigenvalues in the charpol so you can ensure it is indeed the minpol once reduced? Thank you for the help.